Number of complete binary unordered tree-factorizations of n
For prime p, the factorization tree is a single vertex in just one way so that a(p) = 1.
For composite n, the two subtrees at n are a split of n into two factors n = d * (n/d), without order, so that
$$ a(n) \ = \sum_{\substack{d\, |\, n \\ 2\, \le \, d \, \le \, n/d}} a(d)\, a\left(\frac{n}{d}\right). $$
a(1) = 1 is by convention, reckoning 1 as having a single empty factorization.
Examples: For n = 12 and n = 16, there are 2 factor trees:
    12          12
   /  \        /  \
  2    6      3    4
      / \         / \
     2   3       2   2


  16               16        
 /  \            /   \       
2    8          4     4      
    / \        / \   / \     
   2   4      2   2  2  2    
      / \                    
     2   2                   

For n = 12 (above), the tree structures are the same but the values are not the same and are therefore distinct factorization trees.
The same goes for n = 30 leading to 3 binary unordered tree-factorizations:
   30            30           30
  /  \          /  \          / \
 2   15        3   10        5   6
    /  \           / \          / \
   3    5         2   5        2   3

Test cases:



1
2
12
16
30
144
900
9000




1
1
2
2
3
42
171
3166



Summary:
Input: A positive integer n.
Output: a(n), the number of complete binary unordered tree-factorizations of n.
Optional: To simplify things the case n = 1 can be ignored.
Credits: The idea is from an unpublished OEIS sequence yet under consideration.
This is code-golf, so each language's shortest code in bytes wins.

Nice challenge, but can you add an English wording of the math-y codeblock? Many people here don't understand notation like that. Also, this site supports LaTeX (MathJax) formatting, if you surround your LaTeX in \$ on both sides (note the backslash.)

More test cases would be helpfull

I think numbers for which $a(n)=1$ are A007964 and numbers for which $a(n)>1$ are A058080.

Random observation: if $p$ is prime then $a(p^k)$ equals the $k$th “half-Catalan number”.

Added to the OEIS as https://oeis.org/A375120

@TomCarpenter it's the case for both $n=12$ and $n=30$. EDIT: I've edited the post.

What is expected output for 900? Is 900=((23)5)((25)3) different from 900=((25)3)((2*3)*5)? Seems that your formula doesn't agree with your description...

My calculation for a(900) is 168, based on your description. While most other answers are 171. a(900)

And with more tests, the first mismatch value is a(144), which is 41 to my calculation, but 42 with your formula. tio

And based on my implementation, for any prime $p$, we have $a\left(p^k\right)=\text{A001190}(k)$, with the special case $a(1)=0$ here.

Haskell, 49 bytes
f n=max 1$sum[f a*f b|a<-[2..n],b<-[2..a],a*b==n]

Try it online!

Jelly, 14 bytes
ḊŒċP⁼¥Ƈ⁸ß€€ZPS

A monadic Link that accepts a positive integer and yields the count of factorisation trees.
Try it online!
How?
ḊŒċP⁼¥Ƈ⁸ß€€ZPS - Link: positive integer, N
Ḋ              - dequeue -> [2..N]  (an empty list for N=1)
 Œċ            - unordered pairs with replacement -> [[2,2],[2,3],...,[2,N],[3,3],...,[N,N]]
                                                     (an empty list for N=1)
      Ƈ        - keep those Pairs for which:
     ¥ ⁸       -   last two links as a dyad - f(Pair, N):
   P           -     product
    ⁼          -     equals {N}?
        ß€€    - call this Link for each value of each remaining pair
           Z   - transpose  (an empty list for N=1)
            P  - product (vectorises)  (product of an empty list is 1)
             S - sum


JavaScript (Node.js),  57 54 50 bytes
f=(n,i=1)=>n%1?0:n>=++i*i&&f(n,i)+f(n/i)*f(i)||i<3

Try it online!
If there's no way to factor, then it's a prime and return 1

Charcoal, 35 bytes
Ｆ⊕Ｎ⊞υ∨ΣＥΦ…²ι¬∨›×κκι﹪ικ×§υκ§υ÷ικ¹Ｉ⊟υ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
Ｆ⊕Ｎ

Loop n+1 times.
⊞υ∨ΣＥΦ…²ι¬∨›×κκι﹪ικ×§υκ§υ÷ικ¹

Calculate the next a(n) from its nontrivial minor factors, unless there are none, in which case assume a(n)=1. Note that Sum of an empty list is actually None in Charcoal, but it doesn't matter here because that's still falsy.
Ｉ⊟υ

Output the nth entry. (If you wanted all the entries from 0 to n then you could remove the ⊟.)
If you're willing to accept floating-point inaccuracy, then for 31 bytes:
Ｆ⊕Ｎ⊞υ∨ΣＥΦ…·²₂ι¬﹪ικ×§υκ§υ÷ικ¹Ｉ⊟υ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Iterates up to the floating-point square root instead of filtering on the square being not greater than the number being factored.
In practice the floating-point library can take square roots accurately enough for values up to 2¹⁰⁶ which is far more than Charcoal will be able to iterate over before the heat death of the universe.

Vyxal, 13 bytes
λKḢṪvxḂ*Ih∑1∴

Try it Online!
Kinda ugly but it works.
λ             # Define a recursive function f taking n
    vx        # Do a recursive call on each of 
 K            # the divisors of n
  ḢṪ          # aside from 1 and n
      Ḃ*      # Multiply each f(k) by f(n/k)
        Ih    # Take the first half
          ∑   # and sum it
           1∴ # or return 1 if it's empty


Ruby, 53 54 56 bytes
f=->n{[(2..n).sum{|x|x>n/x||n%x>0?0:f[x]*f[n/x]},1].max}

Try it online!
Previous attempt based on a false assumption, now fixed.

Gives the wrong result for very composite perfect squares e.g. 144, 256, 324, 400 etc.

Haskell, 98 #96 92 bytes
s=z#1
z=0:z
(h:t)#i|n<-max 1h=n:zipWith(+)t(do p<-tail$take i s++z;(0<$[2..i])++[p*n])#(i+1)

Attempt This Online!
-2 remembering that thing I ALWAYS forget about
-4 thanks to xnor LMAO
Outputs infinitely. Goofy DP/sieve kind of thing, adding factorization counts up cumulatively.
s=z#1
z=0:z

z is an infinite list of zeroes (i.e. 0 prepended to itself). The sequence s is the function (#) applied to z and 1.
(h:t)#i|n<-max 1h

(#) destructures its first argument into its first element h and remainder t, and its second argument is called i. n is h, unless h is 0, in which case it's 1.
=n: [...] #(i+1)

(#) returns a list where the first value is n, followed by itself called on an incremented i and...
zipWith(+)t( [...] )

every element of t added to the corresponding element of...
do p<-tail$take i s++z;

the concatenation of, for every p in the first i elements of s except the first (infinitely padded with z, so zipWith doesn't truncate)...
(0<$[2..i])++[p*n]

i - 1 zeroes followed by the product of p and n.

z=0:z saves some bytes

R, 70 bytes
f=\(x,y=2,z=0)`if`(x<y^2,max(z,1),f(x,y+1,z+`if`(x%%y,0,f(y)*f(x/y))))

Try it online!
Ugly, but well...
x=n is the real unknown of the function.
y is a potential divider of x. We increment it through recursive calls from 2 to ceiling(sqrt(x)).
z is an accumulator, counting the possible factorizations we have found with dividers smaller than y.
I wanted to golf it much more, with 2 variables instead of 3, but primes and squares of primes are annoying when you cheat too hard. Or maybe there's a smart trick I haven't found.

Desmos, 57 bytes
f(1)=1
f(n)=max(1,∑_{d=2}^{n^½}0^{mod(n,d)}f(d)f(n/d))

Uses the given formula.
Try It On Desmos!
Try It On Desmos! - Prettified
It's really annoying that I have to define a base case f(1)=1 because otherwise Desmos would complain that I don't have a base case for my recursive function, even though f(1) is literally impossible to call recursively given how I defined f. In fact an explicit base case isn't even needed at all, since the base cases are already dealt with within the definition of f. I could literally put a completely absurd base case like f(-100000)=100000000000, for example, and all of the test cases would still work.

05AB1E, 29 20 17 15 bytes
<λèλNÑÂø2äн¦èPO

-9 bytes thanks to a tip of @emanresuA to use an alternative approach
-3 bytes thanks to @emanresuA directly
Try it online or verify the infinite list, starting at n=0.
Explanation:
 λ           # Start a recursive environment
< è          # To output the (implicit) (input-1)'th term
             # (which will be output implicitly afterwards)
             # (Staring implicitly with a(0)=1)
             # Where every following a(n) is calculated by:
   λ         #  Push the list of previous terms [a(0),a(1),...,a(n-1)]
    N        #  Push n
     Ñ       #  Pop and push a list of its divisors
      Â      #  Bifurcate it; short for Duplicate & Reverse copy
       ø     #  Create pairs with the values in the two lists
        2ä   #  Split it into two (almost†) equal-sized halves
          н  #  Pop and keep the first halve
           ¦ #  Remove the first [1,n] pair
    è        #  0-based index each inner value into the previous terms `λ`
     P       #  Take the product of each inner pair
             #  (if n is a prime number, the empty list will become 1)
      O      #  Them sum all of those together
             #  (for prime numbers, the 1 will remain 1)

† I say almost equal-sized halves, since square values will be odd-length lists (e.g. the pairs of 16 are [[1,16],[2,8],[4,4],[8,2],[16,1]], resulting in 'halves' [[[1,16],[2,8],[4,4]], [[8,2],[16,1]]]).

It honestly might be simpler to avoid recursion entirely and instead keep the first n-1 values in the global array while computing the nth, and index into that to compute previous values.

This is the only solution which answer 164 to a(900) so far. while others say 171 instead. And I have no idea about which answer is correct.

@emanresuA Thanks! I didn't realize I could make this into a linear recursive function. In that case 05AB1E does have a good recursive environment builtin, so I won't have to screw around with strings and evals, nor do I need the global array anymore. :) -9 bytes.

@tsh There was likely an error in my approach using the -1, sum, +1. I now use a linear recursive function, as suggested by emanresuA in the comment above yours, and now get a(900)=171 as well.

NDÑ2äнDŠ÷ø¦ can be NÑÂø2äн¦

@emanresuA Of course.. I was actually just trying to shorten that portion, since I had the feeling it could, but didn't try that now pretty obvious approach of halving after creating pairs.

Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 77 71 bytes
Try it online!
a@n_?PrimeQ:=1
a@n_:=Sum[a[d]*a[n/d],{d,Select[Divisors@n,2<=#<=n/#&]}]


It looks like you can cut the first line since we don't have to handle n=1

Google Sheets, 83 bytes
lambda(f,x,y,z,if(x<y*y,max(z,1),f(f,x,y+1,z+if(mod(x,y),,f(f,y,2,)*f(f,x/y,2,)))))

Anonymous lambda function that uses recursion. Based on Evargalo's R answer.
Call the function with the function itself as the first argument, \$n\$ as second argument, \$2\$ third, blank or zero fourth.

Ungolfed:
=let( 
  f, lambda(self, x, y, z, 
    if(x < y * y, 
      max(z, 1), 
      self(self, x, y + 1, z + if(mod(x, y), 
        0, 
        self(self, y, 2, 0) * self(self, x / y, 2, 0) 
      )) 
    ) 
  ), 
  f(f, A1, 2, 0) 
)


SageMath, 91 87 bytes
a=lambda n:int(is_prime(n))or sum(a(d)*a(n//d)for d in range(2,n) if n%d==0 and d*d<=n)

Python apart from the function 'is_prime'.
Shortened with Neil's advice.
Albert.Lang's hint removes 'is_prime':
Python, 74 bytes
a=lambda n:max(1,sum(a(d)*a(n//d)for d in range(2,n)if d*d<=n and n%d==0))


If it really is Python then you can do things like remove unnecessary spaces and change 1 if is_prime(n) else to is_prime(n)or.

Thanks Neil! Python still needs a type conversion despite interpreting 1=True.

There's a space after (2,n) you might be able to remove and also for that ==0 you might be able to use <1.

You can get rid of the sage dependence by using the fact that the sum is nonzero if and only if n is composite. With other optimizations this gets you to 65 bytes pure python.

@Albert.Lang Thank you. Please show us also the 'other optimizations'!

They are linked in my comment. If your browser for some reason doesn't show the link, the code is a=lambda n:sum(a(d)*a(n//d)for d in range(2,n)if(d*d<=n)>n%d)or 1

64 bytes - this goes through $[0..n]$ and performs the product if n<=d*d (which deals with the unordered requirement) and d*d>1 (which excludes d<2) and 1<n%d (which excludes those d which are not factors of n)

@JonathanAllan 60 bytes by moving all looping to the recursion logic.

@Albert.Lang good stuff, now 59 byes (/ works now).
